# my three .col-md-4 won't stay on same row after adding a dropdown button in my navbar?

Tags: html, twitter-bootstrap, button, row

my three columns were all on the same row until I added my dopdown button? Now my last column ( .col-md-4) goes down another row and I didn't change any of the padding (still at 15px each sides).. I don't really understand what happened and how to bring that last column back on the same row as the 2 first ones..

```
    <!-- NAVBAR -->
    <header id="header">
     <nav class="navbar navbar-default navbar-fixed-top">
<div class="navbar-inner">
  <div class="container-fluid">
    <div class="navbar-collapse collapse ">
      <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
        <li class="active"><a href="#">Home <span class="sr-only">(current)</span></a></li>
        <li><a href="#">About</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Blog</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Videos</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Shop</a></li>
      </ul>
 <!--DROPDOWN -->     
     <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
        <li class="dropdown">
          <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" role="button" aria-expanded="false">Contact us <span class="caret"></span></a>
          <ul class="dropdown-menu" role="menu">
            <li><a href="#">Media</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Face to face</a></li>
          </ul>
        </li>
      </ul>
</div>
  </div>
  </div>
  </nav>
  <!--END NAVBAR -->

        <!--ARTICLE -->
<article class="container-fluid">
<div class="row-fluid">
<div class="col-md-4">
<img src="images/P1010471.JPG" width="280" height="209" alt="ocean view"/> 
<p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur<br> 
  adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor<br> incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua.<br> Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud<br> exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip <br>ex ea commodo consequat. </p>
<a href="#">...Learn more</a>
</div>

<div class="col-md-4">
<img src="images/995578_10152891250020352_1581509791_n.jpg" width="280" height="209" alt="catamaran"/> 
<p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur<br> 
  adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor<br> incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua.<br> Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud<br> exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip <br>ex ea commodo consequat. </p>
<a href="#">...Learn more</a>
</div>

<div class="col-md-4">
<img src="images/P1010175.JPG" alt="couple" width="280" height="209">
<p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur<br> 
  adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor<br> incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua.<br> Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud<br> exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip <br>ex ea commodo consequat. </p>
<a href="#">...Learn more</a>
</div>

</div>
</article>
```

Comment: try `row` instead of `row-fluid`

Answer (score 0):

perhaps close your `<header>` tag? I didn't see it

Comment: I'm not even sure you meant to have that header tag up there, see the correct format here, http://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_header.asp

Comment: Doesn't have to be an <article> ?

Comment: I'm not sure how that would effect it